# Removing undefined array indexes after calling array_unique

Tags: php

```
$almostallTech=array();
$almostallTech[]="no";
$almostallTech[]="no";
$almostallTech[]="yes";
$almostallTech[]="yes";
$almostallTech[]="no";
$almostallTech[]="yes";

$almostallTech=array_unique($almostallTech);
printf("size of array: %d<br/>", sizeof($almostallTech));

for ($x = 0; $x < (sizeof($almostallTech)); $x++) {
    printf("%s", $almostallTech[$x]);
}
```

After calling the unique method, it returns the size is 2 - which is correct. However the for loop is giving an undefined offset error.

Upon further checking, if I print out:

```
printf("%s", $almostallTech[0]); - I get no
printf("%s", $almostallTech[2]); - I get yes
printf("%s", $almostallTech[1]); - undefined offset error
```

So the unique function is removing duplicates but keeping the same index of the former array - which is how it works. This should be simple but can't figure out how to remove the empty or more specifically undefined indexes. Tried the array_filter but still not working. Any suggestions?

What I want is after calling the array_unique method, the duplicates are removed but new indexes should apply. i.e.:
I want $almostallTech[0] to contain "no"
I want $almostallTech[1] to contain "yes"

Comment: What is your expected array result ? It looks normal as you used `array_unique()`. Read the manual: http://php.net/function.array-unique

Comment: array_values() would be useful to you. check this link http://php.net/array_values

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Because [`array_unique()`](http://php.net/array_unique) does not re-index the array. You'll have to re-index the array numerically, using [`array_values()`](http://php.net/array_values) or other similar functions:

```
$almostallTech = array_values($almostallTech);
```

Answer (score 1):

Try

```
 $almostallTech = array_values(array_flip(array_flip($almostallTech)));
```

Using array_flip keys from array become values and values from array become keys. Thus you could remove the duplicates but still the indexes would be the same. Now you could use array_values function which returns all the values of the array.

Comment: Why is that necessary? Hate to ask, but what do you think `array_flip` does?

Comment: In array same keys doesn't exist together,i think you know that.

Comment: So what? Now `$almostallTech` will be an array of keys, not values -- that's not required. [See demo](https://eval.in/83295).

Comment: Oh Sorry man forgot one array_flip. i was also trying to set the demo.

Comment: `array_flip(array_flip($arr))` is the same as `array_values($arr)` --Why is `array_flip()` necessary? You're flipping the array multiple times only to come back to the original state? The `array_flip` calls are superfluous.

Comment: First array flip will remove the duplicate values by making it key. second flip will make it back to the value. Just try the code... :)